# Error: Could not read from 'src\pip\_vendor\requests\cookies.py': Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, pycharm

**I was trying to create a new django project using pycharm but it keeps saying bad file descriptor. I completely uninstalled python and pycharm and reinstalled several times but still it did not work. I also noticed that the python scripts file is empty where there should be a easy_install and pip after reinstallation.**

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing src\pip.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\pip.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src\pip.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to src\pip.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\pip.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src\pip.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\pip
copying src\pip\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip
copying src\pip\__main__.py -> build\lib\pip
creating build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\build_env.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\cache.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\configuration.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\download.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\exceptions.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\index.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\locations.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\pep425tags.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\pyproject.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\resolve.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\wheel.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
copying src\pip\_internal\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\distro.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\retrying.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\six.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
copying src\pip\_vendor\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\status_codes.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
copying src\pip\_internal\cli\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\cli
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\check.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\configuration.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\download.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\freeze.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\hash.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\help.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\install.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\list.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\search.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\show.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\wheel.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
copying src\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\commands
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\models
copying src\pip\_internal\models\candidate.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\models
copying src\pip\_internal\models\format_control.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\models
copying src\pip\_internal\models\index.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\models
copying src\pip\_internal\models\link.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\models
copying src\pip\_internal\models\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\models
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\operations
copying src\pip\_internal\operations\check.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\operations
copying src\pip\_internal\operations\freeze.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\operations
copying src\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\operations
copying src\pip\_internal\operations\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\operations
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\constructors.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\req_set.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\req_tracker.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
copying src\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\req
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\deprecation.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\encoding.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\filesystem.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\glibc.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\models.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\outdated.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\packaging.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\setuptools_build.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\typing.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
copying src\pip\_internal\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\utils
creating build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
copying src\pip\_internal\vcs\bazaar.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
copying src\pip\_internal\vcs\git.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
copying src\pip\_internal\vcs\mercurial.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
copying src\pip\_internal\vcs\subversion.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
copying src\pip\_internal\vcs\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_internal\vcs
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\cache.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\heuristics.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\serialize.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\wrapper.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\_cmd.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
copying src\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\certifi
copying src\pip\_vendor\certifi\core.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\certifi
copying src\pip\_vendor\certifi\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\certifi
copying src\pip\_vendor\certifi\__main__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\certifi
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\big5freq.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\big5prober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\chardistribution.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\charsetgroupprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\charsetprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\codingstatemachine.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\cp949prober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\enums.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\escprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\escsm.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\eucjpprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\euckrfreq.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\euckrprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\euctwfreq.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\euctwprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\gb2312freq.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\gb2312prober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\hebrewprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\jisfreq.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\jpcntx.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langbulgarianmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langcyrillicmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langgreekmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langhebrewmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langhungarianmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langthaimodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\langturkishmodel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\latin1prober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\mbcharsetprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\mbcsgroupprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\mbcssm.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\sbcharsetprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\sbcsgroupprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\sjisprober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\universaldetector.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\utf8prober.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\version.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
copying src\pip\_vendor\chardet\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\chardet
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansi.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\initialise.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\win32.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\winterm.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
copying src\pip\_vendor\colorama\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\colorama
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\database.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\index.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\locators.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\manifest.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\markers.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\metadata.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\util.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\version.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\wheel.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
copying src\pip\_vendor\distlib\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\distlib
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\constants.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\serializer.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_ihatexml.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_tokenizer.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_utils.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
copying src\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\html5lib
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\codec.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\core.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\idnadata.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\intranges.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\package_data.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\uts46data.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
copying src\pip\_vendor\idna\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\idna
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\linklockfile.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\pidlockfile.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\sqlitelockfile.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\symlinklockfile.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
copying src\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\lockfile
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\msgpack
copying src\pip\_vendor\msgpack\exceptions.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\msgpack
copying src\pip\_vendor\msgpack\fallback.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\msgpack
copying src\pip\_vendor\msgpack\_version.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\msgpack
copying src\pip\_vendor\msgpack\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\msgpack
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\markers.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\utils.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\version.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\_compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\_structures.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\__about__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
copying src\pip\_vendor\packaging\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\packaging
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\build.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\check.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\colorlog.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\envbuild.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\wrappers.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
copying src\pip\_vendor\pep517\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pep517
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources
copying src\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\py31compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources
copying src\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
copying src\pip\_vendor\progress\bar.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
copying src\pip\_vendor\progress\counter.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
copying src\pip\_vendor\progress\helpers.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
copying src\pip\_vendor\progress\spinner.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
copying src\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\progress
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\core.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\parser.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\test.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\utils.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\writer.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
copying src\pip\_vendor\pytoml\__init__.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\pytoml
creating build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\api.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\auth.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\certs.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests
copying src\pip\_vendor\requests\cookies.py -> build\lib\pip\_vendor\requests

warning: no files found matching 'docs\docutils.conf'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'docs'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\pip\_vendor\six'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\pip\_vendor\six\moves'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyi' found under directory 'src\pip\_vendor'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools'
error: could not read from 'src\pip\_vendor\requests\cookies.py': Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: It might be a version problem... are you using `pip` or `pip3` for `python3.x` ?

Comment: @anuragal while trying to check pip, it says pip is not recognized as internal or external command. The script folder where there should be pip is empty.

Comment: when you install python either 2.x or 3.x, you should have the base commends like pip, wheel, easy_install, etc. If these are missing then there you python install was not proper.
One suggestion is that you can use virtual environment to run your django project, this is actually recommended and comes handy, refer:- https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-for-your-django-projects-using-virtualenv/

Comment: @NishantPatel Yes i do think the problem is with python installation as pip, easy_install is missing in script folder but why the setup process is not showing any error if thats the case.

Comment: did you try setting a virtual environment?

Comment: @NishantPatel somehow i managed to install pip but while creating a virtual enviornment, it still gives an error.

RuntimeError: failed to build image pip because:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 60, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "e:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 42, in install

Comment: Based on your post, I might recommend completely uninstalling Python (again) and then reinstalling it somewhere other than either AppData or Program Files/Program Files (x86) (e.g. try installing it in a folder such as C:\Programs\Python37, for example). Just remember not to use any spaces in the path. If that doesn't solve the issue, there may be some other issue with your system

Answer (score -1):

Delete the Requests Folder from **lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor**. After Deleting, make Sure You have easy_install.exe in Python Scripts Folder, If You do not have that, than you should [read this](https://macstockofficial.blogspot.com/2020/09/solved-python-scripts-folder-is-empty.html). If you have easy_install in Script Folder of Python, then open Command Prompt and write the Command there : `easy_install requests` and this will install latest requests folder in site-packages folder of lib. Now you have to open **lib/site-packages/requests-2.24.0-py3.8.egg** and copy **requests** from it and Go to **lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor** and paste it there.

Comment: Manually touching these files is never a good idea. The fact that OP is having issues with  installing dependencies is usually a symptom of a bigger issue with the Python installation itself or, in the case of this user, with how Python and Pycharm have been configured.